# Showing error and success message on $resource api call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question may be asked several times,but couldnt find any relevant any relevant answers to it.I need to check success and error message on every api call.
But I think I am not using the correct way of calling the api.Please help me.

**my controller.**

```
 'use strict';
    (function (ng, app) {
        app.controller('OrganisationController', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, orgService) {

            $scope.delete = function (row) {
                $scope.OrganisationDelete.M_Organization_Id = row.entity.M_Organization_Id;
                $scope.OrganisationDelete.deleteFlag = true;
                var r = 0
            orgService.orgSVC.UpdateOrg($scope.OrganisationDelete, 
function success(data, status, headers, config, params) {
                //work on success


            }, function error() {
                alert('error');
            })
        });
    })(angular, mainApp);
```

my service

```
'use strict';
(function (ng, app) {
    app.factory('orgService', function ($resource) {

        var orgService = {};
        orgService.orgSVC = $resource('http://localhost:33327/api/Organisation', {}, { InsertOrg: { method: 'POST', isArray: true }, GetOrg: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }, UpdateOrg: { method: 'PUT', isArray: false } });
        return orgService;
    });
})(angular, mainApp);
```

MY API

```
 public int Put(Organisation obj)
        {
            int result = 0;
            if (obj.deleteFlag == true)
            {
                int id = obj.M_Organization_Id;
                result = OrganisationBO.Instance.DeleteOrganisation(id);
            }
            else
            {
                result = OrganisationBO.Instance.UpdateOrganisation(obj);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Reult will either return 0 or 2...
Depending on this ) or 1 i have to show message ,like if 1 then some message and 0 then some message

Comment: depends on your updateorg function,  what does it return,  alert(data) might help you figure that out.   then parse the response and figure out if it was successful.

Comment: alert(data) return....[object object] @notorious-pet0

Comment: alert(data.toSource());

Comment: Yes I tried your answer...still getting undefined or [object object]

Comment: I told you to alert data.toSource() to get the object contents.   Did you do that?    Anyway, I'm over it.  Good luck buddy.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation for [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

In your example, you can write:

```
orgService.orgSVC.UpdateOrg(
    $scope.OrganisationDelete, 
    function success(data){
         //do something on success
    },
    function error(http){
        //do something on error
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...on api i am passing result=1 if success.....so how should I check on success if data is returning success=1

Comment: as was mentioned in another answer, the data is passed as a parameter to the success function, and an http response object is passed to the failure function.

Comment: I am not returning any array,i am just returning a single variable.So whenever i look in my data,I am not able to get my variable or my value.Like I want a message if(variable==true){alert('success')}

Comment: in the success callback, the `data` will be the value that the server returned.

Comment: resources are asynchronous; if you set your variable equal to your resource, it will be set to the promise object; the success callback is executed once the command has been processed by the server and has the actual `data`.

Comment: I don't see why you are still having issues; you check the value of the `data` returned to the server inside the `success()` function; what else isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a error callback following the success callback:

```
orgService.orgSVC.UpdateOrg(
    $scope.OrganisationDelete,
    function (data) {
        //work on success
    },
    function (http) {
        //work on failure
    }
)
```

The parameter passed to the failure callback is [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object, without the resource property.

Please look at the document carefully.

Comment: How should i check if my variable in data returns true or false